# Get the path where the .EXE file has been executed

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe

I have generated an .exe from the script using auto-py-to-exe and it works correctly. The problem comes when it comes to get routes. When I run the program I get this:

```
Script located at:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI26762
Bases are taken from:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI26762/base/
Logs are stored in:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI26762/logs/
```

The .exe is located in C:\Users\username\Desktop\Bot so obviously the path for the folders "base" and "logs" are incorrect. I need to obtain:

```
Script located at:
C:\Users\username\Desktop\Bot
Bases are taken from:
C:\Users\username\Desktop\Bot/base/
Logs are stored in:
C:\Users\username\Desktop\Bot/logs/
```

This is my python code:

```
# GET THE CURRENT LOCATION OF THE SCRIPT
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print('Script located at:')
print(script_dir)

# CHANGE THE WORKING DIRECTORY TO THE CURRENT LOCATION OF THE SCRIPT
os.chdir(script_dir)

new_cwd = os.getcwd()

BASE_FOLDER = new_cwd + '/base/'
LOG_FOLDER = new_cwd + '/logs/'

print('Bases are taken from:')
print(BASE_FOLDER)
print('Logs are stored in:')
print(LOG_FOLDER)

base_csv = os.listdir(BASE_FOLDER)
```

Comment: Read carefully [the relevant pyinstaller docs](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html). The output you get is correct.

Comment: You know it is correct or as stated in the question _obviously the path for the folders "base" and "logs" **are incorrect.**_? There is a small code snippet in the docs that gives you ANY possible path. Did you try to run it and understand the different paths? `sys.executable` will give you the path of the exe file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
I just needed to change:

```
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print('Script located at:')
print(script_dir)
```

to:

```
exe_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
print('Executable located at:')
print(exe_dir)
```